# How do I model multi-variable function?

Tags: java, collections

We know that Map interface models function abstraction in math.  How should I model multi-variable function? For example, to model f(x, y, z), I have two options:

```
Map<List<Integer>, Integer> f1;
```

or

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>> f2;
```

Which one do you think is better?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Neither.

The teqnique you're looking for is called [uncurrying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). We know that a function represents a logical implication:

```
∀ a b. a -> b
```

We also know that if A and B imply C, then A implies that B implies C:

```
∀ a b c. ((a, b) => c) <=> (a => b => c)
```

[Here's proof.](http://www04.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a+implies+%28b+implies+c%29%29+vs+%28a+and+b%29+implies+c) Look at a truth table for logical implication and you'll see that these are equivalent. So how do you represent `A and B` at the type level? You use a product type. The product of two types is a pair, i.e. a type whose values have both of two types:

```
interface P2<A, B> { public A _1(); public B _2(); }
```

You can do the same with triples, or tuples of any arity. Beware though, since this line of reasoning leads you to Heterogeneous Lists, which [aren't pretty in Java](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/heterogeneous-lists-and-the-limits-of-the-java-type-system/).

Also, your `Map` representation is only appropriate for *partial functions*. What's more, the JDK's `Map` interface is designed to be *mutable*, and whoever heard of a mutable function? Here's a better representation:

```
interface F<A, B> { public B apply(A a); }
```

Comment: I think a mutable partial function is needed when the function is being built from ground up (by mapping each (x,y,z) to the value of f).  The function has to be partial because it's being built and has to be mutable in order to be built.

Comment: It's true that if you want to implement your function as a hash table, then your best choice is to build it with a mutable HashMap, but once constructed, you don't want to mutate it again, and you probably want to hide the fact that it's implemented that way.

Answer (score 3):

A third option, which I would prefer, is to define a simple class with three `Integer` fields `x`, `y` and `z` (call it `Triple`, for example) and use `Map<Triple, Integer>`.

If you need this kind of thing often you could make `Triple` itself generic, and use a `Map<Triple<Integer>, Integer>` (or if some of your "functions" need to have arguments of different types it could even be a `Map<Triple<Integer, Integer, Integer>, Integer>` but this is starting to lose readability IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

Your first choice is usually better, since it requires less memory and requires less code to access:

```
Map<List<Integer>, Integer> f1 = ... 
f1.put(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), 7);
Integer v = f1.get(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
```

Use a map of maps only when the access patterns require it, such as

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>> f2 = ...
Set<Integer> keys = f2.keySet();
```